# Unequal sample sizes in two-way repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, anova, repeated-measures, sample-size

For a university course I'm doing research on the effect of veratridine in earth worm axons. We have tested 6 axons (less than expected due to time limitations) in three conditions: control (no drug added), veratridine (10microM), and washout. Within these conditions we stimulate the axons with five different voltage stimulus intervals, and we measure the action potential success rate. So our dependent variable is the action potential success rate, and our independent variables are condition and stimulus frequency. We chose do use a two-way repeated measures ANOVA for statistical analysis.

There's one problem. One of the axons was not functional anymore by the time we tested it in the third condition (washout) so there are no measurements of this axon in this condition. Thus, the washout condition has a smaller sample size than the other conditions (25 (5 worms x 5 frequencies) compared to 30 (6x5)). Is this a problem for the two-way repeated measures ANOVA? Or can we just run the test? (in RStudio).